# Can I use the site to get feedback on a photo?

Tags: discussion

Is it appropriate to use the site to get feedback on photos? I.e. composition, exposure etc.

Comment: This is a duplicate here on meta. See the answer here: http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed (right from the site FAQ).

Comment: Thanks, personally I think this is a missed opportunity. Anyone know of any other sites that do this?

Comment: @Si, that would be a great question for the main site!

Comment: There's already a question like that:  http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2884/where-to-get-feedback-to-my-photos -- however, I would personally like to be able to tap into this community for photo critiques because I'm pretty impressed with the answers on technique.  Does this end up being another SO site?

Answer (score 4):

The community decided that 'general feedback' on photographs is off-topic for this site during the initiation of the group (see the [FAQ](https://photo.stackexchange.com/faq)), however if you're looking for the answer to a specific question regarding some aspect of a photograph you took that would be on-topic. In general examples of on-topic might be:

- What can I do to make the subject's eyes brighter?
- How can I make the background more out-of-focus than the subject?
- What sort of filter can I use to make the greens in this picture *pop* more?

Examples of off-topic might be:

- Is this this good picture?
- What do you think of this picture?
- How could I make this picture better?

Comment: Further to this, there are occasional critique sessions in the [site chat room]http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14) if you do want to cover the "What do you think of this?" type of question.

Answer (score 2):

It can be, as long as you're asking something *specific* about the photo, ideally something technical.

Give context for the photo and explain what exactly you want to get feedback on, what technique in the photo that is of interest.