# Post a photo and ask users how to improve it?

Tags: discussion, faq-suggestion

I'm new to this site. Just wanted to know if it is acceptable to post a photo and ask the users for suggestions, like for sharpness, color, contrast etc...?

If not, kindly suggest any such website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See this: [Can I use the site to get feedback on a photo?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/can-i-use-the-site-to-get-feedback-on-a-photo?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Asking specific questions about how to improve an aspect of a photo are ok, but it's not on-top to just post a photo and ask for broad opinions and suggestions.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Specific questions only. I will try to post and see if it gets flagged! Will wait till EOD and accept your answer.

Answer (score 4):

We've pretty well decided that general "What do you think about this photograph?" questions are too broad. (See [Should Photo Critiques be allowed?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/150/should-photo-critiques-be-allowed) and  [Can I use the site to get feedback on a photo?](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/585/can-i-use-the-site-to-get-feedback-on-a-photo))

***But***, since this is ostensibly a photography site and not merely for camera-gear comparison or a replacement for reading the manuals, I'd really rather err on the side of tolerance for broad questions about specific photographs. I'm a lot more interested in that than another *"16-92mm f/3.2 vs 14-87mm f/3.9 which to buy?"* or *"Is the Nicatax 9000 a good camera?"*. I'd certainly rather do a little bit of back and forth with the poster to improve photo critique questions than have *another* question asking how to calculate the distance to or size of an object given certain inputs.

***However***, with that said, the questions do need to be in a basic Q&A format, rather than just looking for comments. Pick an aspect that *you* aren't happy with in your photograph, and focus our attention on that. Otherwise, if you're perfectly happy with the photograph already and just hoping for +1s... there are plenty of other sites for that.